# Need help on how to convert Jquery .change() to React.js to show/hide divs

Tags: reactjs, hide, onchange, show

I have a multi select field that shows/hide various  based on what is selected.
The values of the  are equal to their respective  class.

Need help converting the below Jquery code to react to show/hide appropriate s

*****The HTML*****

```
<select id="my_fields" name="my_fields" multiple="multiple">                                        
    <option value="gas">Gas</option>
    <option value="car_wash">Car Wash</option>
    <option value="parking">Parking</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>


<div class="gas hide">show/hide gas</div> 
<div class="car_wash hide">show/hide car_wash</div>
<div class="parking hide">show/hide parking</div> 
<div class="other hide">show/hide other</div>
```

*****The JQuery*****

```
$( "#my_fields" ).change(function () {
      $( "#my_fields option:selected" ).each(function() {                                  
            $( "."+ $(this).val() ).show();
      });

      $( "#my_fields option:not(:selected)" ).each(function() {
            $( "."+ $(this).val() ).hide();
      });
});
```

*****The React*****

```
.....imports and class.....

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value: "",
    show:false,
  };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

 }
 handleChange(event) {

   this.setState({
     value: event.target.value,
     show: true
   })
 }


render() {
 var show = {
  display: this.state.show ? "block" : "none"
};

 return (
  <select    
       name="my_fields"
       multiple
       value={this.state.value}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
   >                                        
      <option value="gas">Gas</option>
      <option value="car_wash">Car Wash</option>
      <option value="parking">Parking</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>

   <div class="gas" style={ show }>show/hide gas</div> 
   <div class="car_wash" style={ show }>show/hide car_wash</div>
   <div class="parking" style={ show }>show/hide parking</div> 
   <div class="other" style={ show }>show/hide other</div>

 )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any react code to show to start?

Comment: Thanks for looking, Jeremy.  React posted above.  Essentially, handleChange will show  all the <div>s which is a start, but I only want the  to show <div>'s that have the same class as the value(s) selected in the select input.  When option is not selected, then div should be hidden.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question. Is the idea that if you select gas and car_wash the div gas and car_wash should be shown? If so, you need to keep track of the currenly selected values in your state and toggle the show variable based on whether or not an option is selected. It looks like your state is wrong, and your change handler should check event.target.options and iterate over it to figure out which options are selected.

Comment: yes, exactly! and if I decide to un-select the option, the div hides. all div's are initially  hidden.  -- Trying re-create the .each()function in the Jquery code above, but in react.js

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works with some modifications -

```
state = {
  values: []
};

handleChange = event => {
  const options = Array.from(event.target.options);
  const selectedOptions = options.filter(op => op.selected);
  const selectedValues = selectedOptions.map(op => op.value);

  this.setState({ values: selectedValues });
}
```

with changes to your `return` JSX

```
...
{this.state.values.includes('gas') && <div class="gas">show/hide gas</div>}
{this.state.values.includes('car_wash') && <div class="car_wash">show/hide car_wash</div>}
{this.state.values.includes('parking') && <div class="parking">show/hide parking</div>}
{this.state.values.includes('other') && <div class="other">show/hide other</div>}
```

Comment: Thank you Prithviraj. What you have provided only work if one option is selected.  I need to show each div based on the multiple option selected.

Comment: Yes, that works.  I ended with something similar (in answer below) , but your is  less code.  I was also missing the ".includes" in the conditional

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange(event) {
     var options = event.target.selectedOptions;
     var value = [];
      for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
          value.push(options[i].value);
        }
      }


      this.setState({
        expenseCategory:[].slice.call(event.target.selectedOptions).map(o => {
              return o.value;
        }) 
      });
}
```